# Convert arbitrary number of columns to Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset, apache-spark-mllib

How to convert a group of arbitrary columns to a Mllib Vector?
Basically, I have first column of my DataFrame with a fixed name and then a number of arbitrary named columns each having Double values inside.

like so:

```
name  |  a  |  b  |  c  |
val1  | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
val2  | 2.0 | 1.0 | 5.0 |
```

Could be any number of columns. I need to get a DataSet of the following:

```
final case class ValuesRow(name: String, values: Vector)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in a simple way using `VectorAssembler`. The columns that are to be merged into a `Vector` are used as input, in this case all columns except the first.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("val1", 0, 1, 1), ("val2", 2, 1, 5)))
  .toDF("name", "a", "b", "c")

val columnNames = df.columns.drop(1) // drop the name column    
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(columnNames)  
  .setOutputCol("values")

val df2 = assembler.transform(df).select("name", "values").as[ValuesRow]
```

The result will be a dataset containing the name and values columns:

```
+----+-------------+
|name|       values|
+----+-------------+
|val1|[0.0,1.0,1.0]|
|val2|[2.0,1.0,5.0]|
+----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector

val ds = Seq(
  ("val1", 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  ("val2", 2.0, 1.0, 5.0)
).toDF("name", "a", "b", "c").
as[(String, Double, Double, Double)]

val colList = ds.columns
val keyCol = colList(0)
val valCols = colList.drop(1)

def arrToVec = udf(
  (s: Seq[Double]) => new DenseVector(s.toArray)
)

ds.select(
  col(keyCol), arrToVec( array(valCols.map(x => col(x)): _*) ).as("values")
).show
// +----+-------------+
// |name|       values|
// +----+-------------+
// |val1|[0.0,1.0,1.0]|
// |val2|[2.0,1.0,5.0]|
// +----+-------------+
```